# Название элемента

Tags: css

Как правильно называется плашка с текстом поверх картинки?
Никак не могу найти и вспомнить.

Например, как [тут](http://jemand.ru/examples/tekst-poverx-kartinki-na-css.html)

Comment: overlay?...

Answer (score 1):

Хм.. Может Caption (подпись, заголовок)?

Comment: нет, есть какое-то красивое название =)

Comment: @frgs, не tooltip ли часом? (и нет, это не tooltip)

Comment: @frgs никогда о таких вообще не слышал, на самом деле. Image caption да и все. Зачем оно вам вообще?))

Comment: Часто это называется header (а снизу - footer)

Answer (score 0):

> Как правильно называется плашка с текстом поверх картинки?

например, watermark